# My test iOS devices generated real adMob clicks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, ads

I'm new in AdMob.
I started from today to edit my 1st app.
I use Google manual and some other helps, because I'm trying to keep iAd and I want to use AdMob if iAd is not available etc..
So, I put my 2 test devices (iPhone and iPad) in the following rows:

```
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ @"xxxxxxxx", @"xxxxxxxx" ];
[self.admobBannerView loadRequest:request];
```

where in the place of xxxxxxxx are my devices IDs.
I got these IDs from the debugger when I run AdMob on the device for the first time.

For 2 or 3 minutes when I start testing my banners in all my screens, the banners are OK - test banners, 320x50 pixels etc.. but after that I see that the banners become real. Yes, I tried to click 3 or 4 times on these "real" banners, yes, they are real! And I am a violator, yes? :)
I refresh my stats and I see about 20 cents... all these impressions and clicks are generated from my tests devices and I'm worried about all of this situation.
I want to use not only simulator.
Thanks!

Edited to include code from comment:

Here is the rest of my adMob code:

```
self.admobBannerView.delegate = self; 
[self.view addSubview:self.admobBannerView]; 
[self.admobBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Is this loadRequest (2nd) is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run your app on your device. In the Debug Area AdMob will give you your test id. It should look similar to this:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[ @"testDeviceNumber" ]
```

Take this and request an ad with it. For example, you would request an interstitial test ad like so:

```
    // AdMob Interstitial
    interstitial_ = [[GADInterstitial alloc] init];
    interstitial_.adUnitID = MY_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[@"insertTestDeviceNumberHere"];
    [interstitial_ loadRequest:request];
```

Then, to get live AdMob ads again, just remove or comment out `request.testDevices = @[@"insertTestDeviceNumberHere"];`

---

Edited to account for code added by user:

Your problem is in this line: `[self.admobBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];`

With `[GADRequest request]` you are creating a brand new request. Change it to:

```
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ @"insertTestDeviceNumberHere"];
    [self.admobBannerView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:self.admobBannerView];
```

Comment: Yes, I do the same things, exactly as you write here..
But the real situation is that for 2 or 3 minutes on test device I see test banners, after that banners become real, when I click on the banner, I open real page from the ad.
So, this problem generated for me about 200 impressions and about 10 clicks and I hope AdSense team will be lenient for me :)
I will use simulator for future tests. I do not want to be a "criminal" :)

Comment: @Panayot could it be that you are creating a new banner somewhere else in your code? I've never had the test ads switch to regular ads before. I wouldn't worry about AdMob laying down the hammer on you. It takes a lot more than a few innocent clicks to get their attention.

Comment: @ Daniel, as you see, I'm new here and I can not vote.
So, yesterday I was thinking exactly that possibility - if I duplicate anything.
Here is the rest of my adMob code:

self.admobBannerView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.admobBannerView];
[self.admobBannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]]; 

Is this loadRequest (2nd) is my mistake?...

Comment: @Panayot I've edited my answer to include the code included in your comment.

Comment: yes, you are right.
I added these 3 rows with the test device (in 1st my post, the original) and not analyse... My effort was for another thing - how to combine iAd and adMob (iAd first, and when not available, to load adMob). In last about 6 months I use so often Stackoverflow for help, as anonymous user. It was my 1st question here and thank you so much! :)

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused here, what should we do with `request.testDevices` if we want to release the app (finished with testing and wanting to submit the app) and getting the device ids from all other users (real users, not test users) in our admob account?

Comment: @Reza.Ab just comment out or remove the `request.testDevices`.